# Преобразование с помощью Python значений из столбца в значения в строке, разделенные др. от друга запятыми

Tags: python

Добрый день уважаемые коллеги,
про помочь разобраться в решении следующей задачи.
У меня есть перечень значений (кодов товаров, кот. более 10000 тыс. ед.) в столбце листа Excel. Моей задачей является превращение этого столбца в таблицу таким образом, чтобы значения друг от друга были разделены запятыми в строке, и самих значений в одной строке было 100 ед.
Например, есть такой столбец с данными:

```
       Товар.Код
 0     152
 1     153
 2     154
 3     155
 4     156
 ...
 10000  745
```

Хотел получит такую таблицу:

```
152, 153, 154, 155, 156
252, 253, 254, 255, 256
...
(100-ая строка) 741,742,743,744,745
```

Для этого, насколько мне позволяют начальные знания Python, пишу следующий код:

```
import pandas as pd
rt_df_1 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\...\\список.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист1') 
rt=rt_df_1.transpose()
```

и получаю строку (таблицу) вида:

```
            0   1   2   3   4
Товар.Код   152 153 154 155 156
```

далее пытаюсь применить костыльный способ поставить запятые:

```
print('152 {} 153 {} 154 {} 155 {} 156'.format(','))
```

и получаю ошибку вида:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Прошу помочь разбить один большой столбец данных на столбец со значениями в строке в 100 ед. и разделенных друг от друга запятыми.

Comment: Это просто для вывода на экран, или что то планируется с этим делать дальше?

Comment: Далее хотел бы выгрузить в excel файл для работы со значениями в строках нового столбца. Для меня важно получить именно 100 значений, разделенных др. от др. запятыми.

Comment: вам не нужно "пихать" запятые в таблицу pandas - это глупость. вам просто нужно разбить длинную строку на строки по сто значений и отдать в эксел.

Comment: Особенность именно в наличии запятых между значениями, далее я буду использовать эти данные в фильтрах метрик инструментов веб-аналитик. В подобные фильтры можно поместить не более 100 значений, разделенных др. от друга запятыми. Важно "разбить" исходный столбец в Python.

Comment: сделайте ``.replace(" ", ",")`` в нужной строке. Это заменит все пробелы на запятые. Еще лучше сделать через регулярку, вдруг там по два или три пробела подряд.

Comment: вы не понимаете. таблица пандас - это чистый набор значений. разбивайте их по 100 на строку, а уж выгружайте как хотите, хоть с запятыми, хоть с поздравлением с китайским новым годом.

Comment: Подскажите, как я могу разбить столбец на 100 значений на строку. С этим я уже имею определенные проблемы...

Comment: например, список lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] делим по n = 3 chunks = [lst[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(lst), n)] chunks = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]

Answer (score 1):

Можно изменить "геометрию" массива с помощью `np.reshape()`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'c:\test\список.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист1',header=None)
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,100)) # потребуется доп. обработка, если количество значений не кратно 100
df.to_csv(r'c:\test\список.csv',header=None,index=None)
```

**На входе:** столбец в Excel.
**На выходе:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дополнение.** Один из вариантов решения при кол-ве значений, некратных 100 - дополнить до количества, кратного 100, например, нулями:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(r'c:\test\список.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист1', header=None)
rest = (100 - df.shape[0] % 100) % 100
df = pd.DataFrame(np.append(df.values, np.repeat(0, rest)).reshape(-1, 100))
df.to_csv(r'c:\test\список.csv', header=None, index=None)
```

Вариант с `resize()`:

```
import pandas as pd # pandas здесь только для ввода/вывода из Excel / в CSV
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(r'c:\test\список.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист1', header=None)
v = np.array(df.values) # во избежание ошибки "массив не владеет своими данными"
v.resize((v.shape[0] // 100 + min(v.shape[0] % 100, 1), 100)) # преобразование "на месте"
pd.DataFrame(v).to_csv(r'c:\test\список.csv', header=None, index=None)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, у меня как раз случай, о кот. вы пишите. Значений, на самом деле не 10 000, а "с хвостиком", не кратно 100. Могли бы вы помочь скорректировать код для подобного случая?

Comment: @НикитаПетров см. дополнение

Comment: Спасибо вам большое @Алексей Р ! Вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

генерируем датафрейм

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l = np.random.randint(0, 351, 300)
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

получили датафрейм с 350 рядами чисел. далее:

```
df_100 = [df.iloc[i:i+100, :] for i in range(0, len(df), 100)] # разбиваем по 100
for i in range(0, len(df_100)):   # пишем в csv-файлы
    df_100[i].T.to_csv(f"df-{i}.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

получаем csv-файлы вида "df-0.csv"

Для данного примера он будет выглядеть типа такого:

```
163,337,163,320,196,199,253,206,262,189,105,341,120,140... и далее до сотого значения
```

Comment: Спасибо вам @strawdog! Помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Будем считать, что у вас уже есть строка (вектор 152...10000). Я получу эту строку искусственно:

```
numer_set = [x for x in range(152, 10001)]
```

Тогда

```
for i in numer_set:
    print(str(i)+',', end=' ')
    k+=1
    if k == 100:
        print('\b')
        k=0
```

даст нужное вам.